# getting error of variable not defined In EJS but I am defining a const variable

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am defining the variable 'message' but still getting error 'message not defined'.
I am using res.redirect method for showing error in login page with res.flash(). But if user opens the login page for the first time the variable message should be blank.

when I am opening the login page I am getting this error

```
exports.login = (req,res)=>{
   const message=req.flash('error')
    res.render('login',{ message });
    
}
```

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <p><%= message%></p>
        <a href="/signUp" class="btn signUpBtn">Sign Up</a>
    </nav>
```

```
ReferenceError: /Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/views/login.ejs:13
    11| <body>
    12|     <nav class="navbar">
 >> 13|         <p><%= message%></p>
    14|         <a href="/signUp" class="btn signUpBtn">Sign Up</a>
    15|     </nav>
    16|     <div class="loginMainCont">

message is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:12:26)
    at login (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1017:7)
    at exports.forLearning (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/server/services/render.js:12:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/abhijeetarya/web development/tessers2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `const message = req.flash("error") ?? "";`

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: The stack trace says this render is coming from `server/services/render.js`, line 12. What does that file look like?

Comment: thanks for looking at this stack and solving my problem. I did a silly mistake. there are two Functions for rendering login page. I forgot to add my message data in first one.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%_ if(typeof message !== "undefined"){ _%>
<p><%= message%></p>
<%_ } _%>
```

try doing this in your ejs file

Comment: this works too!